# Advanced XPath SelectNodes criteria

Tags: powershell, xpath

I have reached a stumbling point in my understanding of XPath. I can do basic selections without too much trouble, but I have a need now to select nodes based on not only what node they are a part of, but also based on if they contain a specific node, and I keep finding myself going down the path of a large selection then doing the Loop and If dance to whittle it down. And somehow I think I am missing some nifty trick in XPath to do exactly this in a single statement.

So, given the XML below, I would like to end up with a set of Computer nodes, based on a particular Location id and the presence of a particular value in a Set. So, $location = Amsterdam & $set = Viz should return just the A-1 computer, but $location = Amsterdam & $set = Arch should return all three computers in Amsterdam.

So, is this something that can be done purely in the XPath statement? And if not, is there a nifty Powershell pipeline trick? Or is my best bet to use XPath to address Location and Loop and If to strain out the Sets?

```
<Management>
  <Computers>
    <Location id="Amsterdam">
      <Computer id="A-1">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Arch</Set>
          <Set>Viz</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
      <Computer id="A-2">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Arch</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
      <Computer id="A-3">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Arch</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
    </Location>
    <Location id="Berlin">
      <Computer id="B-1">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Viz</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
      <Computer id="B-2">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Arch</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
      <Computer id="B-3">
        <ConformSets>
          <Set>Arch</Set>
        </ConformSets>
      </Computer>
    </Location>
  </Computers>
</Management>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath form to return `Computer` element based on `Location`'s `id` attribute and `Set` descendant element value :

```
//Location[@id='some_id']/Computer[ConformSets/Set='some_set_value']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, dang. Post a question then have an epiphany. None of my Google searching had turned up any examples of predicates other than attributes of the specific node, or Descendants deeper than Child nodes. But on a lark I threw the relative path to Set into the predicate, and Woot, that works!

```
$selection = $global:jobsXml.selectNodes("/Management/Computers/Location[@id='$($location)']/Computer[ConformSets/Set='$($set)']")
```

Comment: Aaaaand, Ninja'd by har07 to boot! ;)

Comment: Side note: subexpressions for variables in strings are only required if you want to access array elements (`"$($var[0])"`) or properties of objects (`"$($var.foo)"`). For plain variables `$var` or `${var}` suffice.

Comment: Ansgar, good clarification. In my actual code I am using a form to get inputs into a hash table, so my actual predicates use things like $script:choice.location, and when simplifying for posting I didn't simplify as much as I could/should have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `..` to work your way back up from a matching (child)node:

```psh
$location = 'Amsterdam'
$set      = 'Arch'
$xpath    = "//Location[@id='$location']/Computer/*/Set[text()='$set']/../.."

$xml.SelectNodes($xpath)
```

or (as suggested by [@har07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817869/1630171)) use a predicate with a relative path for the `Computer` nodes:

```psh
$location = 'Amsterdam'
$set      = 'Arch'
$xpath    = "//Location[@id='$location']/Computer[ConformSets/Set='$set']"

$xml.SelectNodes($xpath)
```